# Texture2D GetPixels - Finding pixels that are not transparent. Problem as finding more than expected

Tags: unity, level-design, levels

I am trying to make a level design system where I use a low resolution png file with certain pixels filled. My code will turn this location of the pixel in the image into placement of platforms in my game.

But I test the following code with a png i made with only 1 pixel in it (the rest are transparent). But the result is it finds 4 every time. Is it possible there is a discrepancy between the Gimp png and the texture that Unity sees. (In GIMP I used pencil 100% hardness 1px width. There are also settings for 'resolution' of the image, which i left at defaults):

```
public class LevelBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
public Texture2D sourceTex;
Color32[] pixels;
int pixelsFound = 0;

private void Start()
{
    pixels = sourceTex.GetPixels32();
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pixels[i].a != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("found colored pixel. total: " + ++pixelsFound);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Questions like this should include details of how you've set up your image and its import settings, since as you've discovered those details are the key to solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I was going to delete the question but just in case somebody else needs the same help, all I had to do was set the Textures Import Settings in Unity Inspector. It needed Read/Write enabled, and Non-power of 2: None.

Now it finds the pixels correctly for my purposes

Heres the full code to get just basic (one type of pixel is recognised right now, either empty or not, but i intend to add color coding to add many varients of objects using one texture):

```
public class LevelBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject platform_prefab;
public float spacing;

public Texture2D sourceTex;
Color32[] pixels;
int pixelsFound = 0;

Color32[,] pixels2d;


private void Start()
{
    pixels = sourceTex.GetPixels32();
    int width = sourceTex.width;
    int height = sourceTex.height;
    pixels2d = new Color32[width, height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            pixels2d[x, y] = pixels[x + y * width];
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < pixels2d.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < pixels2d.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            if (pixels2d[x,y].a != 0)
            {
                GameObject platform = Instantiate(platform_prefab);
                platform.transform.position = new Vector3(x * spacing, y * spacing, 0);
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```